HOW TO LEFT JOIN IN A VARRAY FIELD
I need help on find the correct way to write a query in oralce db. Now I have this query:
SELECT a.ID, a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.ADDRESS, b.GROUP
FROM schema.tale_name a,table(a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.MARGINI_DERVT) b

In this query schema.tale_name a is the table which has multiples sql types. One of this is a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.MARGINI_DERVT which is a varray of another sql type nested in a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT which is also a sql type.
The problem with this query is that it only retrieves rows where a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.MARGINI_DERVT exist but I need to retrieve all the rows since there isn't a where condition.

i mean something like schema.tale_name a(+) in the from statement

Have you tried that? If so what happened? Also you should look at using modern JOIN syntax, including LEFT [OUTER] JOIN, rather than Oracle's old syntax. If it doesn't do what you expect then include sample data and current/expected results - preferably a [mcve].

Hey Alex, and what should be the join? This doesnt't work "FROM schema.table a LEFT OUTER JOIN table(a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.MARGINI_DERVT) b on a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.MARGINI_DERVT = b"

But b and a doesn't have common columns. B is simply a column in A and it is a varray of types.

If I'm following - which would be easier if you edited the question to include the type and table definitions, sample data and expected results - you may be looking for outer apply - but are you really still on version 11g, as you've tagged the question?

That old A, B join syntax has been obsolete for 30 years now. Time to move on.

If you're on a recent version of Oracle (12c+) you can use outer apply:
SELECT a.ID, a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.ADDRESS, b.GROUPa
FROM tale_name a
OUTER APPLY table(a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.MARGINI_DERVT) b

In earlier versions (as you've tagged this 11g) you can probably get away with a normal outer join with a dummy join condition, though this might break down with a more complicated query:
SELECT a.ID, a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.ADDRESS, b.GROUPa
FROM tale_name a
LEFT JOIN table(a.LIQUIDITA_DERVT.MARGINI_DERVT) b ON 1=1

fiddle
